# Decorator that can be used in class constructor in Nest.js and uses injectables itself

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator, typescript-decorator

Using Nest.js to inject dependencies, how can a custom decorator be created that itself injects and uses services, and that can be called in a class constructor? I'm looking for a generic answer, however my current use case is tapping into app configuration object with minimal code.

Given the following `ConfigService`,

```js
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  private config: Config;

  constructor() {
    // Do something to load a valid configuration into this.config.
  }

  get() {
    return this.config;
  }
}
```

Instead of having to inject `ConfigService` itself and call its `get()` method, I would like to directly use the configuration via a parameter decorator (here `@Config`) like so:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AnotherService {
  constructor(@Config() private config) {}

  doSomething() {
    console.log("I have access to configuration:", this.config);
  }
}
```

Simply writing a standard decorator function and using it in an injectable class' constructor results in Nest not being able to resolve that class' dependencies, namely the decorator.

If it has any impact, you can assume that the `ConfigService` is provided by and exported from a global module. However, would be nice to have a solution that works with normal modules as well.

Thank you!